# Azure Mysql HTTP REST API . Get JSON Web Token

Tags: mysql, rest, api, azure, http

I'm trying to connect to my Azure Mysql via http rest api (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/mysql/) without success. The problem is that i can't get the JSON Web Token from my Web App. Situation:

Azure Web App ----- rest api ----> Azure MySql

I guess i need to 'register' this Mysql Server resource in active directory but seems i can't do it.

I followed this tutorial ([https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/03/17/accessing-azure-app-services-using-azure-ad-bearer-token-2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/03/17/accessing-azure-app-services-using-azure-ad-bearer-token-2/)) but i have the same problem : i can't register MySql in Azure Active Directory .

So, how can i obtain a JSON Web Token for Mysql HTTP REST API ?

Thanks!

-------- AD PROPIETARY ROLE FOR MYSQL RESOURCE (NOT MYSQL SERVER) --
[image]
---------------- CODE ----------------------------------------------

```
    //
// https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/03/17/accessing-azure-app-services-using-azure-ad-bearer-token-2/
//
public static class AzureActiveDirectory
{
    // the AD Authority used for login.  For example: https://login.microsoftonline.com/myadnamehere.onmicrosoft.com 
    public static string authority = "";
    // the Application ID of this app.  This is a guid you can get from the Advanced Settings of your Auth setup in the portal
    public static string clientId = "";
    // the key you generate in Azure Active Directory for this application
    public static string clientSecret = "";
    // the Application ID of the app you are going to call.This is a guid you can get from the Advanced Settings of your Auth setup for the targetapp in the portal
    public static string resource = "";


    static public async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetS2SAccessTokenForProdMSAAsync()
    {
        var task =  await GetS2SAccessToken(authority, resource, clientId, clientSecret);
        return task;
    }

    static async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetS2SAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret); 
        AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false); 
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(
            resource,  // the resource (app) we are going to access with the token
            clientCredential);  // the client credentials
        return authenticationResult; 
    }

}





  AzureActiveDirectory.authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/********/";
        AzureActiveDirectory.clientId = "********";                                             
        AzureActiveDirectory.clientSecret = "********";
        AzureActiveDirectory.resource = "https://management.azure.com/";

        try
        {


            AuthenticationResult token = await AzureActiveDirectory.GetS2SAccessTokenForProdMSAAsync();

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.AccessToken);
            var resp = await client.GetAsync("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/*******/resourceGroups/MYSQL/providers/Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers/shoplister/firewallRules?api-version=2017-12-01");

            Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e); }
```

--------------- AFTER CHANGES NOW GETTING UNAUTHORIZED ------------

[image]

Comment: That API seems to be for managing Azure MySQL databases, creating them etc. If what you want is connect to the MySQL database, I think you should connect with a username + password on the MySQL server as usual.

Comment: Thanks, but i need to connect with rest api to update Mysql firewall rules from a Web App.

Comment: Ahh okay. Then you'll need to register the app in Azure AD and assign the app a role on the mysql resource. Then you can acquire access tokens to call the API from Azure AD using client credentials flow.

Comment: I did what u said but always getting : 'the application named '...' was not found in the tenant named '...'.  Which 'resource id' i have to reference? i added my webapp to the group resources control access that contains Mysql Server but don't know how to reference it

Comment: Resource URI would be `https://management.azure.com/` I believe. It's the identifier for the API you want to call.

Comment: Great, seems i'm in my last step to do it. Now i'm getting an error when i get the rest api call: 403-Forbidden. I checked clientId and clientsecret. Resource is https://management.azure.com and authority is: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Directoyrid}/oauth2/token .    And finally the URL called is:   https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{sub-id}/resourceGroups/MYSQL/providers/Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers/{my-server-name}/firewallRules?api-version=2017-12-01        . And my webapp has propietary rol in MYSQL group.... what is probably causing the 'ForbiddenError' ?Many thanks again!

Comment: I forgot. The token i receive has idToken, TenanId and Userinfo null values but i get an accesstoken string value

Comment: Authority should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id-here/`

Comment: And you need to attach the access token as `Authorization: Bearer tokengoeshere`

Comment: Thank you for your patient juunas! I'm newbie with Azure  and i really need this service . Now i'm getting Unauthorized . I have my webapp as propietary role in the resourcegroup 'MYSQL' (that contains the mysql server ). May be i have to get an user token than an accesstoken? All seems ok, any idea? :-)

Comment: May be editing some value in the manifest WebApp file in AD?

Comment: error="invalid_token", error_description="The authentication scheme of Authorization is not supported."

Comment: That's odd, could you share some of the code?

Comment: juunas i just added information, hope helps u

Comment: I see your problem :) You need to specify the authorization header as `new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AccessToken)`

Comment: client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AccessToken);  -------> Now getting 'Forbidden'   :((

Comment: Hmm, well it's an improvement but not sure why that happens now. You can inspect the access token you get at https://jwt.ms and check it has the right azure ad tenant id. Also double check that is the same app as what you assigned in Azure portal. Its possible you have given the role to an app with the same name.

Comment: It works! yeah, the problem was a duplication with name in role and app. You will always have a beer if u come to Barcelona... best regards! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm compiling the important points from our discussion in the comments that led to a solution:

- Use `https://management.azure.com` as the `resource` identifier when acquiring the access token
- Use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id-here/` as the authority (you can also use a verified domain name instead of the id). This defines which AAD tenant you authenticate against
- The access token must be attached with `new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AccessToken)` in C#, so that the resulting header is `Authorization: Bearer tokengoeshere`
- Finally make sure you have granted permissions to the right app. There can be apps with an identical or similar name.